# Docker Windows host - Installing nVidia driver on the Linux VM used for Linux containers

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, nvidia-digits

I'm trying to use [DIGITS](https://developer.nvidia.com/digits) from nVidia on my Windows machine without building it myself. I thought it's easier to use Docker (starting to change my mind).

My understanding is that Docker on Windows is basically using a Linux VM to actually run Docker.. so, the Docker interface on host Windows is simply interacting with the Docker installed on the Linux VM which will then host a guest Linux container to run DIGITS.

When I try to run the DIGITS container, I get the following error:

```
============
== DIGITS ==
============

NVIDIA Release 18.05 (build 425957)

Container image Copyright (c) 2018, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.
DIGITS Copyright (c) 2014-2017, NVIDIA CORPORATION. All rights reserved.
Caffe Copyright (c) 2014, 2015, The Regents of the University of California (Regents). All rights reserved.
Torch Copyright (c) 2016, Soumith Chintala, Ronan Collobert, Koray Kavukcuoglu, Clement Farabet. All rights reserved.
TensorFlow Copyright (c) 2017, The TensorFlow Authors.  All rights reserved.

Various files include modifications (c) NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.
NVIDIA modifications are covered by the license terms that apply to the underlying project or file.

WARNING: The NVIDIA Driver was not detected.  GPU functionality will not be available.
   Use 'nvidia-docker run' to start this container; see
   https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/nvidia-docker .

  ___ ___ ___ ___ _____ ___
 |   \_ _/ __|_ _|_   _/ __|
 | |) | | (_ || |  | | \__ \
 |___/___\___|___| |_| |___/ 6.1.1

Did you forget to "make pycaffe"?
A valid Caffe installation was not found on your system.
Use the envvar CAFFE_ROOT to indicate a valid installation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/opt/digits/digits/__main__.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/digits/digits/__main__.py", line 53, in main
    import digits.config
  File "/opt/digits/digits/config/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import (  # noqa
  File "/opt/digits/digits/config/caffe.py", line 230, in <module>
    executable, version, flavor = load_from_path()
  File "/opt/digits/digits/config/caffe.py", line 57, in load_from_path
    import_pycaffe()
  File "/opt/digits/digits/config/caffe.py", line 126, in import_pycaffe
    import caffe
  File "/usr/local/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, \
  File "/usr/local/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

DIGITS docker image needs nVidia drivers to be installed **on the host** AFAIK. I think the error here means the drivers are not installed. However, I don't know how to install nVidia drivers on the Linux host since that's simply a VM used by Docker interface on Windows.

Is there a way to access that Linux VM and install nVidia drivers on it?